# read file line by line and remove characters shell script

Tags: bash

The purpose of the program is to remove punctuation in text, and can handle option `-c` to remove character you want.

```
#!/bin/bash
old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$’\n’
if [ “$1” == “-c” ];then
 if [ -f $2 ];then
  for line in $(<$2)
  do
   echo $line | tr -d $3
  done
  IFS=$old_IFS
 else
  echo $2 | tr -d $3
 fi
else
 if [ -f $1 ];then
  for line in $(cat $1)
  do
   echo $line | tr -d '[:punct:]'
  done
  IFS=$old_IFS
 else
   echo $1 | tr -d '[:punct:]'
 fi
fi
```

And the text file is:

```
"Twaddle!", you say?  I’ll have you know
there’s a {deep} truth
in what I said.
```

If i just want to remove punctuation, the result is:

```
Twaddle you say  Ill have you k
iheres a deep truth
 what I said
```

Other characters are lost, like `now` of `know`.  Can anyone find what the problem is?

Comment: This script is completely stupid. `tr` can filter an entire stream/file and remove or substitute multiple characters.

Comment: Better tools for doing such tasks are using text editors I think like `sed` and `awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulties that you are having are due to the use of non-ASCII characters.  In particular, look at:

```
IFS=$’\n’
```

That line does not work as intended because those are not normal ASCII single quotes.  The result is that the character `n`, among others, end up in the variable IFS.  This causes word splitting on `n` which is why the `n` disappears out of `know`.

Use instead:

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

The double-quotes are also nonstandard and should be replaced with ASCII double-quotes.  In particular, this line:

```
if [ “$1” == “-c” ];then
```

should be replaced with:

```
if [ "$1" == "-c" ];then
```

#### Alternative script

The script's logic can be rearranged and simplified:

```
#!/bin/bash
remove='[:punct:]'
if [ “$1” == “-c” ]
then
    remove=$3
    shift
fi
if [ -f $1 ]
then
  tr -d "$remove" <"$1"
else
  echo "$1" | tr -d "$remove"
fi
```

Comment: Twaddle you say  Ill have you know
in what I saidtruth (the result after changing them, loss one line)

Comment: @user3606466 You may have other special characters that I didn't catch.  You report that your script is now, among other things, moving the word `truth` from mid sentence to the end of the sentence?  I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: In text file, the should be separated to three lines. The first line is: "Twaddle!", you say?  I’ll have you know    And second line is : there’s a {deep} truth   Third line is: in what I said.   But after trying your method, the result just shows two lines and 'truth' move to the end, that's not right.

Comment: @JAC I just tried it again with (1) your code with my modifications and also with (2) my alternative code.  Both work for me.  However, if your file had a carriage return character in place of a newline at the end of the second line that could cause the third line to partially overwrite the second.  That would match your result.  What program are you using to create these files?

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" = '-c' ]
 then
   Pattern="$( echo "$3" | sed 's/[]\[&\\{}()"]/\\&/g' )"
   File="$2"
 else
   Pattern="[[:punct:]]"
   File="$1"
 fi
sed -i "s/${Pattern}//g" ${File}
```

using sed with few security about special char from "reduce" regex panel on your script